# How can I see how many bytes were read and written on disk from explain analyze output to determine if I reduced thrashing

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following explain analyze buffers and I'm trying to find how much data is being read and written to the disk.

```
 Update on table_a  (cost=0.00..6050652.34 rows=0 width=0) (actual time=103086.007..103086.242 rows=0 loops=1)
   Update on table_a_0 table_a_1
   Update on table_a_1 table_a_2
   Update on table_a_2 table_a_3
   Update on table_a_3 table_a_4
   Buffers: shared hit=13 read=4464047 dirtied=6 written=155
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..6050652.34 rows=4 width=18) (actual time=9121.741..103035.231 rows=1 loops=1)
         Buffers: shared read=4464021 written=129
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a_0 table_a_1  (cost=0.00..1659192.00 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=9121.736..36064.106 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = '2140c9b1-0731-4d47-b0a3-b3eac46b2b88'::uuid)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 34793136
               Buffers: shared read=1224258 written=33
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a_1 table_a_2  (cost=0.00..1413476.38 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=24383.427..24383.429 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = '2140c9b1-0731-4d47-b0a3-b3eac46b2b88'::uuid)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 29664510
               Buffers: shared read=1042670 written=32
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a_2 table_a_3  (cost=0.00..1517186.80 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=20257.856..20257.856 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = '2140c9b1-0731-4d47-b0a3-b3eac46b2b88'::uuid)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 31829265
               Buffers: shared read=1119321 written=32
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a_3 table_a_4  (cost=0.00..1460797.15 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=22329.476..22329.672 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: (id = '2140c9b1-0731-4d47-b0a3-b3eac46b2b88'::uuid)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 30642013
               Buffers: shared read=1077772 written=32
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=19 read=9 written=3
 Planning Time: 24.771 ms
```

I'm trying to determine if I can reduce thrashing on the db by changing up some queries and trying to see which metrics I can use to determine if my attempts are successful

Comment: 1 buffer is (in almost every configuration) 8kB. `shared read=1224258` means 1.2 million buffers, 9.3GB. In your case you need an index on the id column.

Comment: What does that mean for the write then? 33 * 8kB?

Comment: Yes, correct, 33 buffers of 8kB each

Comment: Thats really shocking considering this was only 1 row getting updated, so not sure why there would be so much data written on each partition table

Comment: The big shock however, is the fact you don’t have a useful index on the id column. Because of this the database has to read gigabytes of data to find a few rows

Comment: This is a temporary table and I was didn't add an index yet as I was just experimenting with the analyze output. There will obviously be an index that gets used when the query actually runs. I was just curious about finding disk usage at this point

Comment: Experimenting is good! But you have to realize that some behavior that you see, writing 264kB for 1 record, is because of other choices you made: Not creating an index. Reading 30+GB of data for one record has also a much bigger impact on your system than writing 264kB.

Answer (score 0):

The update itself took only 51 milliseconds (pretty long, actually), but the database has to find the row you want to update first. Since you don't have an index on the `id` column, it has to search all 120 million rows in your table.